# Pandas for large(r) datasets

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pandas

I have a rather complex database which I deliver in CSV format to my client. The logic to arrive at that database is an intricate mix of Python processing and SQL joins done in sqlite3.

There are ~15 source datasets ranging from a few hundreds records to as many as several million (but fairly short) records.

Instead of having a mix of Python / sqlite3 logic, for clarity, maintainability and several other reasons I would love to move ALL logic to an efficient set of Python scripts and circumvent sqlite3 altogether.

I understand that the answer and the path to go would be Pandas, but could you please advise if this is the right track for a rather large database like the one described above?

Comment: Complexity of answer in pandas is going to depend on how large these are.  In particular if they fit in memory (I assume not?)

Comment: Thanks JohnE. I need to do some calculations, I may be able to fit this in memory... But let's assume the worst case -- large database which does not fit in RAM. Still worth learning and pursuing Pandas?

Comment: I couldn't say.  Possible for sure, but worthwhile is something only you could figure out.

Comment: Yes, it is still worth learning pandas. You can read_csv in chunks using chunksize parameter and load data of any size. That said, it may be faster to load it with a native import function - which is typically faster with large files by ~10X. You can still reformat and pipe output if your system supports is to parallelize the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using Pandas with datasets > 20 GB in size (on a Mac with 8 GB RAM).

My main problem has been that there is a know [bug in Python](https://bugs.python.org/issue24658) that makes it impossible to write files larger than 2 GB on OSX. However, using HDF5 circumvents that.

I found the tips in [this](http://sdsawtelle.github.io/blog/output/large-data-files-pandas-sqlite.html) and [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/) article enough to make everything run without problem. The main lesson is to check the memory usage of your data frame and cast the types of the columns to the smallest possible data type.